# Get the woocommerce product price in javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the woocommerce product price in a javascript(jQuery) file and I can't get php file to work. I know that somehow it needs to be linked with woocommerce. I'm not sure how.

this is my js that calls for php file:

```
    $.ajax({
  url: '/get-product-price.php',
    Id: productId,
  success: function(data) {
    $('.canvas-total-price > span').text(data);
  }
});
```

and this is my *get-product-price.php* file:

```
<?php
$price = get_post_meta( $Id, '_regular_price', true);
echo $price;
 ?>
```